# Laravel 4.2 Session Database Driver Read / Write Host

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-4

I configured the way I separate the database to read and write.

```
'mysql' => [
'read' => [
    'host' => '192.168.1.1',
],
'write' => [
    'host' => '196.168.1.2'
],
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'database'  => 'database',
'username'  => 'root',
'password'  => '',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
],
```

But now, I want to change the database driver in the session and I want to be able to read and write operations to a single host of the session value.

How can I only run on a single host in the session process without disturbing the above structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

We are adding a new connection into the first database.php connections.

```
'session' => array(
        'host' => "HOST_NAME",
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

then we give the name of the connection a little bit before we install the connection value in session.php file.

```
'connection' => "session",
```

Thats it.